# How can I remove URL links from cells in openrefine?

Tags: openrefine

How can I remove all URL in the text via openrefine? Is there any transform code for that? My data have many URL links different from each other in the texts. And I want to remove these links.

For example my data have like that text in the cells

"put returns between paragraphs for linebreak add 2 spaces at end *italic* or **bold** indent code by 4 spaces backtick escapes `like _so_` quote by placing > at start of line to **http://foo.com/**"

And I want to delete only URL links in the cells. After removing it should be;
"put returns between paragraphs for linebreak add 2 spaces at end *italic* or **bold** indent code by 4 spaces backtick escapes `like _so_` quote by placing > at start of line to"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transformation should do the trick :

```
value.replace(/(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?/, '')
```

Comment: It is working well. Thank you so much. How can I remove all punctuations in a similar way?

Comment: OpenRefine uses [Java Regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  with the format `value.replace(/YOUR REGEX/, 'REPLACEMENT STRING')` So, try something like `value.replace(/\p{Punct}/, '')`